# What variations are there in the Jewish canon?

Tags: tanach, navi-prophets, ketuvim

Most Jewish communities have the 24 books of the Tanakh as canon, but the Ethiopian Jewish canon varies somewhat, including, e.g., the Book of Judith and the Book of Jubilees.

Are there any other Jewish communities that traditionally either do not have the whole Tanakh in their canon or have additional books in their canon?

Comment: Are you willing to include the samaritins?

Comment: @DoubleAA, if it leads to an interesting answer, why not?

Comment: that's circular. It's only interesting if you're willing to include them

Comment: That was a jocular way of saying I'm willing to include them. (Though I didn't have them in mind ahead of time.)